# how to save and restoring the view data when switching between multiple views in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have 3 views in my AngularJs web application.In the View1 I am displaying a table which is getting data from controller by clicking button. If I navigate to another view and return to the first view, I am not able to see the table, again I need to press the button to get table in the view. So, I need to having table in view1 when returning back from other page.

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('OpenOrdersController', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    'salesOrgService',
    'dataService',
    function($scope, $http, salesOrgService, dataService, $routeParams,
            $location, SVC_DOMAIN, IMAGE_BASE) {
        console.log("Enter OpenOrdersController");
        $scope.data = dataService;
        $scope.OpenOrdersSummary = $scope.data.data.responsedata;
        $scope.user.model.salesorg = "2015";
        $scope.getOpenOrders = function(salesOrg) {
            $scope.OpenOrdersSummary = {
                "SapExOpenOrderTab" : [ {

                    "col1" : "0009421175",

                    "col2" : "000000",

                    "col3" : "0000"
                },

                {

                    "col1" : "0009421820",

                    "col2" : "000000",

                    "col3" : "0000",

                } ]
            };

        };
    } ]);
app.service('dataService', function() {
this.data = {}
this.data.responsedata = '';
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
    data-ng-disabled="!user.model.salesorg "
    data-ng-click="getOpenOrders(user.model.salesorg)">Refresh</button>
</td>
<table
    class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-bordered ordersTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-hide="OpenOrdersSummary.SapExOpenOrderTab.length > 0"
            class="error">
            <td colspan="4">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <strong>This request may take some time ; please wait for
                        response !!! </strong>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr
            data-ng-repeat="sampleProductCategorie in OpenOrdersSummary.SapExOpenOrderTab | orderBy:orderby:reverse">
            <td>{{sampleProductCategorie.col1}}</td>
            <td>{{sampleProductCategorie.col2}}</td>
            <td><a
                ng-href="#/openOrdersDetail/{{sampleProductCategorie.col1}}">{{sampleProductCategorie.col3}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here I am initializing the table object in service based on some stack overflow questions and assigning table data in controller. My requirement is when am returning to index.html view from other view I want to see previous table data in index.html view. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, the data is not coming from the service. It seems to be hardcoded in the controller and set to the scope variable OpenOrdersSummary on demand (button clicked). If your data is going to ultimately be hardcoded, you can forego the service altogether -- if it will eventually come from an external source, then the service makes sense, and you should assign the data value to the service's data.servicedata variable. That will cause data to be displayed as soon as the controller is loaded at line

```
$scope.OpenOrdersSummary = $scope.data.data.responsedata;
```

If instead you need the data to be lazy loaded, then you need the service to implement some kind of loadData function that will set the service's data.servicedata variable at on demand.

If that doesn't clarify, let me know and I can help write some sample code.

Comment: actually the data is coming from web service, but I hard coded here.  My problem is I am not able to see the table after navigating to another page and return back. I didn’t get the solution from your answer. If there is any thing help me.

Comment: Ok, the way I would handle the issue is by resolving the data in the route... assuming you are using ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#user-content-resolve). If you are not using ui-router, then add a caching mechanism to your service so that it caches the service response data after the first request (clicking the button). After that, the service's data.responsedata should always contain the data (since services are singletons), so by setting the scope's OpenOrderSummary to the service's data.response data on load, it should set it between view loads.

Comment: You could alternatively save the data using either local storage (https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage),  angular's $cacheFactory (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) or angular cache (https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I should do according to your example.

As you mention in the example the response data is hardcoded, try to have http request in the service.

```
app.service('dataService', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.data = {
    responsedata: ''
  }

  this.makeRequest = function() {
    //...Use $http to make request and set response from request to this.data.responsedata
  }

  return this;
}]);
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/reggmezb/3/